# How to understand AssertThat (JUnit)?

Tags: eclipse, junit, assert

To understand JUnit, I have written the following code. In particular, I am interested in the assertThat()-method.

```
package test;

public class Equals {

    private String x ; 

    public Equals(String a){

        this.x = a; 
    }

    public Equals equals(Equals x ){
            return x; 
    }
}
```

Then I make a test class to test the equals()-method.

```
package test;


import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EqualsTest {

    @Test
    public void testEquals() {
        Equals t1 = new Equals("test");

        assertThat(t1, t1.equals("test"));
    }


}
```

Eclipse underlines assertThat with red and recommends: Create method assertThat(Equals, boolean).

[image]

The other assert-methods like assertEquals() and so on are quite straightforward, but this one is not so intuitive for me. I do not understand that. Please help.

best regards,

Comment: You're supposed to use a matcher with `assertThat`. Just search the web or read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You must use some matcher with this method, not a boolean.

For instance, you can use the `is` matcher for your purpose:

```
assertThat("this string", is("this string"));
```

Take a look at this : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/matchers.html

Comment: It's recommend that you provide some context when you give a link (perhaps a snippet or sample code). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

`assertThat` is part of the Hamcrest assertion library. Please have a look at Hamcrest's web site: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of JUnit now include hamcrest.

In fact, org.junit.Assert.assertThat 's method signature is

```
public static <T> void assertThat(T actual,
                              org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> matcher)
```

You can use this way,

```
assertThat(t1, equalTo("test"));
```